# Is there a way to maintain an ordered array within a mongo document?

Tags: arrays, ruby, mongodb

I have a mongo document with a field of times:

`` field :times, type: Array, default: []` ``

Currently, on update, I will take another time, find its place and overwrite the whole array on save. Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to do this automatically through Mongo somehow?

Comment: What kind of elements do you store in the array and how do you sort them?

Comment: I'm only putting floats in the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$sort` in `$push`

```
$push: {
    innerElement: {
        $each: [
            {
                "new-entry": ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
                "createdOn": ISODate()
            }
        ],

        $slice:-10,

        $sort: {'createdOn': 1}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$position` operator when doing a `$push` in a `update(...)`:

```
>db.students.save({ "_id" : 1, "scores" : [  50,  60,  70,  100 ] })

>db.students.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
        scores: {
           $each: [ 20, 30 ],
           $position: 2
        }
     }
   }
)

> db.students.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "scores" : [  50,  60,  20,  30,  70,  100 ] }
```

See - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position